# Xlsxwriter duplicates records in cell

Tags: python, excel, xlsx, xlsxwriter

Does anyone knows why this code creates excel file with duplicated lines in cell. I mean I get sth like abcd\nabcd in cell. If I pass less rows in my excel list i get normal output. Also if there isn't \n in element it doesn't duplicate.

```
import xlsxwriter

excel = [['abcd\n','defg\n','hijk\n'],
         ['abcd\n','defg\n','hijk\n'],
         ['abcd\n','defg\n','hijk\n'],
         ['abcd\n','defg\n','hijk\n'],
         ['abcd\n','defg\n','hijk\n'],
         ['abcd\n','defg\n','hijk\n'],
         ['abcd\n','defg\n','hijk\n'],
         ['abcd\n','defg\n','hijk\n'],
         ['abcd\n','defg\n','hijk\n'],
         ['abcd\n','defg\n','hijk\n'],
         ['abcd\n','defg\n','hijk\n'],
         ['abcd\n','defg\n','hijk\n'],
         ['abcd\n','defg\n','hijk\n'],
         ['abcd\n','defg\n','hijk\n'],
         ['abcd\n','defg\n','hijk\n'],
         ['abcd\n','defg\n','hijk\n'],
         ['abcd\n','defg\n','hijk\n'],
         ['abcd\n','defg\n','hijk\n'],
         ['abcd\n','defg\n','hijk\n'],
         ['abcd\n','defg\n','hijk\n'],
         ['abcd\n','defg\n','hijk\n'],
         ['abcd\n','defg\n','hijk\n'],
         ['abcd\n','defg\n','hijk\n'],
         ['abcd\n','defg\n','hijk\n'],
         ['abcd\n','defg\n','hijk\n'],
         ['abcd\n','defg\n','hijk\n'],
         ['abcd\n','defg\n','hijk\n']]

with xlsxwriter.Workbook('testxd.xlsx') as workbook:
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    cell_format = workbook.add_format({'text_wrap': True})
    
    for row_num, data in enumerate(excel):
        worksheet.write_row(row_num, 0, data,cell_format)
```

Unwanted Output:

[image: Unwanted Output]

Correct Output:

[image: Correct Output]

Comment: how is the normal output? I tested your code and it produces a excel file with the given data 3 columns and 27 rows

Comment: Did you get text in cells like "abcd", "defg".. or text is duplicated in each cell? I want to get 3 col 27 row but in my file each cell has duplicated text.

Comment: "The file you requested has been deleted". I've added screenshots of what i get and what i want to get in orignal post. I see that \n makes it work weird but i need to have it in my real data.

Comment: As you can see text in each cell is duplicated, but i don't know why it happens

Comment: I tested without the newline \n and it gives the correct output, the original code the cells are bigger because of the newline, now the text is wraped https://file.io/P5qZ7fSJsaa6

Comment: The point is in my original file with data, I have a lot of new lines which need to be in one cell. Data I paste here is only for test. I can't past original data, because of personal data of mine clients.

Comment: im experiencing similar behavior and can't point why

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code, as is, and I don't see any duplication issue:

[image]

Comment: Seems like it appears only on Windows. But I need to use Windows on my computer.

Comment: That isn't the case. I tested the output with 2 versions of Excel on Windows and 2 versions on macOS and the output appears the same in all cases (as it should).

Comment: Do you have any clue why does it duplicate at my computer?

Comment: No, I have never seen a report of that behaviour and there is nothing in XlsxWriter or the xlsx file spec that would cause that. Are you sure you are running the code you posted and viewing the file output from it? Maybe change out on the input lines to make sure. You could also try to upgrade xlsxwriter but I don't think that will change anything.

Comment: Yes, I run exactly the same code. Also xlsxwriter is updated to the newest version. I will try on another computer or reinstall python but that's weird. I spent a lot of time wondering what I did wrong in my code, but then I just pass some lists as input, and it's acting weird. If i put less elements in list it works okay :/ Also in first answer @user16822867 run my code and got the same output file.

Comment: Reading the comments above it isn't clear to me that @user16822867 got the same output you see. Maybe others reading this can run the code and report what they see.